# no Wifi adapter card after Update to 21.10 - XPS 13 7390

Tags: wireless, network-manager, 21.10, iwlwifi, xps

After updateing to 21.10, my wifi card is not working anymore.

`sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network DEAKTIVIERT     
       Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
       Produkt: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       Hersteller: Intel Corporation
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:02:00.0
       Logischer Name: wlp2s0
       Version: 1a
       Seriennummer: 68:54:5a:b2:e7:b0
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.13.0-28-generic firmware=67.8f59b80b.0 cc-a0-67.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
       Ressourcen: irq:18 memory:9e200000-9e203fff
  *-network
       Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
       Physische ID: 3
       Bus-Informationen: usb@2:1.3
       Logischer Name: enxa0cec8ea3285
       Seriennummer: a0:ce:c8:ea:32:85
       Größe: 1Gbit/s
       Kapazität: 1Gbit/s
       Fähigkeiten: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       Konfiguration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.12.11 duplex=full firmware=rtl8153a-4 v2 02/07/20 ip=192.168.20.165 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

`rfkill list`

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Ubuntu: 21.10

Kernel: 5.13.0-28-generic

I only see this, no wifi adapter card
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yQBj.png

Edit 1_:

`lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Rivet Networks Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [1a56:1653]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

`sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

```
[    5.335259] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    5.335260] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:9340:55438a77
[    5.404454] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.442731] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-67.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.442757] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-66.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.442776] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-65.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.442797] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-64.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.444897] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    5.444912] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[    5.445449] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 63.c04f3485.0 cc-a0-63.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.681039] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    5.828245] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected RF HR B3, rfid=0x10a100
[    5.906588] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: 68:54:5a:b2:e7:b0
[    5.930038] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

I've also disabled and enabled the wifi into the bios.
And also the keyboard shortcut did not help at all.

The Laptop see the wifi card but do not show it into the gui.

Edit 2:

the output of

```
ls /lib/firmware/ | grep '.ucode'
```

```
amd-ucode
intel-ucode
iwlwifi-1000-3.ucode
iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-16.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode
iwlwifi-3168-21.ucode
iwlwifi-3168-22.ucode
iwlwifi-3168-27.ucode
iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
iwlwifi-3945-2.ucode
iwlwifi-4965-2.ucode
iwlwifi-5000-1.ucode
iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode
iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
iwlwifi-6000g2b-5.ucode
iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
iwlwifi-6050-4.ucode
iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-16.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-16.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-16.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-21.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-27.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-21.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-27.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-31.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode
iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
iwlwifi-8265-21.ucode
iwlwifi-8265-22.ucode
iwlwifi-8265-27.ucode
iwlwifi-8265-31.ucode
iwlwifi-8265-34.ucode
iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-33.ucode
iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode
iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode
iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-41.ucode
iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-43.ucode
iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-33.ucode
iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode
iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode
iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-41.ucode
iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-43.ucode
iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-48.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-53.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-55.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-59.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-62.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-63.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-66.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-67.ucode
iwlwifi-cc-a0-68.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-48.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-50.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-53.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-55.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-59.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-62.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-63.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-66.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-68.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-48.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-50.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-53.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-55.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-59.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-62.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-63.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-66.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-68.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-48.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-50.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-53.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-55.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-59.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-62.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-63.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-66.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-68.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-48.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-50.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-53.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-55.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-59.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-62.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-63.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-66.ucode
iwlwifi-Qu-c0-jf-b0-68.ucode
iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-48.ucode
iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-50.ucode
iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-53.ucode
iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-55.ucode
iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-59.ucode
iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-62.ucode
iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-63.ucode
iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-66.ucode
iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-67.ucode
iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-68.ucode
iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-48.ucode
iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-50.ucode
iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-53.ucode
iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-55.ucode
iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-59.ucode
iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-62.ucode
iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-63.ucode
iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode
iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-68.ucode
iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0-67.ucode
iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0-68.ucode
iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-64.ucode
iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-67.ucode
iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-68.ucode
iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-64.ucode
iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-68.ucode
iwlwifi-so-a0-jf-b0-64.ucode
iwlwifi-so-a0-jf-b0-68.ucode
iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode
iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-62.ucode
iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-63.ucode
iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode
iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-67.ucode
iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-68.ucode
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133828/discussion-on-question-by-snowest-no-wifi-adapter-card-after-update-to-21-10-x).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wireless interface, driver, firmware and the question remains of why Network Manager doesn't pick up the interface and manage (connect!) it.

In our chat we saw this in dmesg:

```
CPU: 5 PID: 1308 Comm: NetworkManager Tainted: G OE
```

I suspected that an update to your system might bring an update either to NM itself or one of its dependencies. When you attempted to update, there were many errors and warnings indicitive of stale repositories in your /etc/apt/sources.list. We made several amendments to it and removed backport-iwlwifi-dkms as it is sometimes but not always helpful.

After these changes, you were able to upgrade many packages and, after a reboot, your wireless is working correctly.