# No Wi-Fi after updating to 23.10

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, 23.04, 23.10

I was using both wifi on 23.04 successfully. After updating to 23.10, my XPS network adapter was failing to load:

1. The network adapter is a `Qualcomm QCA6390` and the driver is identified as `ath11k_pci` based on the information from `sudo lshw -C network`
2. This is what `sudo dmesg | grep ath11k` shows up:

```
[   14.266832] ath11k_pci 0000:71:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0xa6100000-0xa61fffff 64bit]
[   14.266855] ath11k_pci 0000:71:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   14.267085] ath11k_pci 0000:71:00.0: MSI vectors: 32
[   14.267089] ath11k_pci 0000:71:00.0: qca6390 hw2.0
[   14.663649] ath11k_pci 0000:71:00.0: chip_id 0x0 chip_family 0xb board_id 0xff soc_id 0xffffffff
[   14.663662] ath11k_pci 0000:71:00.0: fw_version 0x10121492 fw_build_timestamp 2021-11-04 11:23 fw_build_id 
[   14.663703] ath11k_pci 0000:71:00.0: failed to fetch board-2.bin or board.bin from QCA6390/hw2.0
[   14.663705] ath11k_pci 0000:71:00.0: qmi failed to fetch board file: -2
[   14.663706] ath11k_pci 0000:71:00.0: failed to load board data file: -2
```

3. The problem occurs in both present kernels: 5.14 and 5.17 (both OEM)

I found a couple of related posts here that showed slightly different problems with responses that did not solve my problem:

- [no Wifi adapter card after Update to 21.10 - XPS 13 7390](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1390635/no-wifi-adapter-card-after-update-to-21-10-xps-13-7390)
- [No Wi-Fi adapter found after upgrading to 23.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1494133/no-wi-fi-adapter-found-after-upgrading-to-23-10)
- [Qualcomm Artheros WiFi card not detected/stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1429758/qualcomm-artheros-wifi-card-not-detected-stopped-working)

My question is obviously: how to get my wireless adapter to load correctly!?

Comment: You should have the 6.5 kernel in 23.10 you may need to reinstall linux-generic

Answer (score 1):

After reading other posts, I realized that the `dmesg` error message says **"failed to fetch board-2.bin or board.bin from QCA6390/hw2.0"**. I learned from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1429758/qualcomm-artheros-wifi-card-not-detected-stopped-working) how to check for the existence of such **BIN** files. In my case:

```
> ls /usr/lib/firmware/ath11k/QCA6390/hw2.0/
amss.bin.zst  board-2.bin.zst  m3.bin.zst  Notice.txt.zst
```

So, weirdly enough, the files ARE present in the distribution but are compressed using ZST. So, all I had to do was:

1. install the ZST command: `sudo apt install zstd`
2. get inside the firmware folder the kernel is trying to use: `/usr/lib/firmware/ath11k/QCA6390/hw2.0/`
3. uncompress the files: `sudo unzstd *`
4. reboot the system